# PDO get number of followers

Tags: php, pdo, count

Here is my code

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM user_follow WHERE user = :user";

        $stmt1 = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql1);  
        //where clause                                 
        $stmt1->bindParam(':user', $username);
        $stmt1->execute();  
while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo  '</br>Followers: </br>'.$row1['followers'].'</br>';


}
```

It show the name of the followers but I would like a implementation in PDO to also show the amount in numbers of the `$row1['followers']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the count you can use [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) function:

```
$stmt1->execute();  
$count = $stmt1->rowCount();
echo  '</br>Followers: </br>'.$count.'</br>';
```

so it's just echo $count

Comment: your code is right but you forgot the var simbol **$** ´echo  '</br>Followers: </br>'.$count.'</br>';´

Comment: `COUNT()` in SELECT could have been another/additional option.